# Dash v2.7+ does not support Internet Explorer. Please use a newer browser

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to follow along with a Dash tutorial for python. However, when I try opening a tab with my localhost port on which my Dash App is meant to be running on, nothing is shown. When I inspect the source code I am told "Dash v2.7+ does not support Internet Explorer. Please use a newer browser.". However, I am using Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome so that does not really make sense to me.

Here is my source code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from plotly import express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Hello World")
    ]
)


app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8152)
```

I was therefore wondering what the issue is as I have tried looking it up but there does not seem to be an answer?

Comment: What does "nothing is shown" means? Is it an empty page? "Site can't be reached" or similar?

Comment: it gives me just a blank page

Comment: That does sound pretty weird. Just to double check, you're saying that after running your Dash app, when you load up Google Chrome and go to http://localhost:8152 you get the above behaviour?

Comment: Yeah that was what was happening but it seems to have fixed itself and is now running as desired. I don't know what fixed it though.

Comment: @JackFrench Did you ever figure this out, I'm having the same issue when trying to serve outside the local enviroment